# How can we force a min allocation and a max allocation to a stock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am running the code below and it gives me the results you see at the end of the code sample.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.optimize as sco
import datetime as dt
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
np.random.seed(777)


start = '2020-06-21'
end = '2021-06-21'
# N = 90
# start = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
# end = dt.datetime.today()



tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','UNH','RTX','VZ','V','WBA','WMT','DIS','RLLCF','GME','AMC','DOW']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()

def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns
  
def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(thelen)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record


returns = table.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
num_portfolios = 10000
risk_free_rate = 0.0178



def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
    results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    
    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T
    
    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T
    
    print("-")
    print("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print("\n")
    print(max_sharpe_allocation)
    print("-")
    print("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print("\n")
    print(min_vol_allocation)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
    plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)
    

display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate)
```

[image]

How can I set a constraint to force the minimum allocation to be 2%, thereby forcing RLLCF to have  2% allocated to it, and allocate the rest of the 98% according to the same relative weights that are applied now?  I totally understand that it will be non-optimized if we start applying constraints, but I'm trying to test a specific use case. Also, I'd like to set a max constraint to something like 12%, and have the rest distributed according to the same relative weights that are applied now. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is somewhat lost in the sauce here...  It appears you are just randomly generating a large number of "portfolios" and comparing the output, which isn't really optimization.  If you want to fix one of the weights, why can't you do that; and if it is 2% then just normalize "the other weights" to total 98% and be done with it?

Comment: Well, what are you proposing? What is your intended solution?

Comment: To restate:  You don't really have a framework that supports your question.  If you want to go about this with randomly generating weights, but you want one (or more) of them to be fixed, assign those and then randomly generate the remainder.  If you want to do a "better" job optimizing, there are probably completely different frameworks in NLP that would be good to explore, but that is a different question.

Comment: There is a somewhat non-intuitive reformulation of the max-Sharpe-ratio problem into a standard QP (Quadratic Programming) problem. Here you can directly add lower and upper bounds for the individual assets (or any other linear constraints). High-quality QP solvers are readily available. You can also add "0 or minimum allocation" or "maximum number of assets in the portfolio". Those restrictions require MIQP solvers.

Comment: Ok. I will re-think this and come at it from a different angle. Thanks guys!